# How to check if auto-play is enabled in bxslider

Tags: bxslider

Once a button (#my-button) is clicked, I want to check if the auto-play feature is enabled for the slider. I tried below, but it returned undefined object

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});

$('#my-button').click(function(){
    console.log(slider.auto);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious way of determining if auto is enabled (ie. See if slider is moving by itself,) we can see which of the autoControl buttons, `.bx-start` and/or `.bx-stop` has the class `.active`.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var slider = $('.bx').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});

$('.status').click(function() {
  if ($('.bx-stop').hasClass('active')) {
    console.log('Auto is inactive');
    $('.display').val('Inactive');
  } else {
    console.log('Auto is active');
    $('.display').val('Active');
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<ul class='bx'>
  <li class='slide'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/000/fff?text=1'></li>
  <li class='slide'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/00f/eee?text=2'></li>
  <li class='slide'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/0e0/111?text=3'></li>
  <li class='slide'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/f00/fff?text=4'></li>
  <li class='slide'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/fc0/000?text=5'></li>
  <li class='slide'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/fff/000?text=6'></li>
</ul>


<button class='status'>Status</button>
<output class='display'></output>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thanks. However, I am just wondering what did you mean by "the obvious way of determining if auto is enabled (ie. See if slider is moving by itself,)". Is there any quick command for that as well (just for learning).

Comment: If bxSlider auto is enabled, then it will move on to the next slide without user interaction (i.e. click, drag, touch, etc.). You'll be able to see it move, therefore you know it's enabled. Unless you are sight impaired, if so, my apologies.

Comment: Lolz, I thought you were talking about something through coding. Didn't get the funny part of that.

Comment: Text is one dimension communication, and besides that your mindset is code oriented. I knew you'd catch on eventually. 